# Node.js/ Express POST Request Body Parsed into Incorrect JSON

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, polymer

I have a Polymer `core-ajax` component sending some data to a Node.js server. The data is being sent correctly (I can parse it with a Go web server) but Node parses it as the stringified body being a key to a blank string in a JSON object:

```
{ '{"count":-1,"uid":1}': '' }
```

This is the code that sends the request from Polymer:

```
sendCount: function(change) {
  console.log("Sending...");
  console.log(JSON.stringify({"count": change, "uid": this.uid}));
  // ^ This prints: {"count":-1,"uid":1}
  this.$.ajax.body = JSON.stringify({"count": change, "uid": this.uid});
  this.$.ajax.go();
}
```

This is the Node code:

```
app.post("/post", function(req, res) {
  console.log(res.headers);
  console.log(req.body); // Prints { '{"count":-1,"uid":1}': '' }
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

When I get the response back it has returned the malformed JSON.

How am I supposed to parse JSON in Node correctly?

Also:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: set `ajax.body` equal to the object, not `JSON.stringify(object)`.

Comment: Did you set the `core-ajax` attributes `contentType="application/json"` and `handleAs="json"`? I did it that way and stringified the JSON before setting it as the ajax.body, it works fine with node.

Comment: @idleherb that's done it. Want to submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `core-ajax` attributes `contentType="application/json"` and `handleAs="json"` and stringify the JSON before setting it as `ajax.body`.